# Windows 8 Workstations Default Programs

Tags: domain, windows-8, defaults

I'm trying to set up default programs for all windows 8 workstations, UAC is disabled via GPO and hence the default programs for opening pdf files, mp3s etc default to the metro apps.
This results in users unable to play these files since metro apps require UAC turned on.

The easy option is to turn on UAC however i'm wondering if there's a way to set pdf files to open in adobe reader and mp3 in VLC.

I've tried numerous solutions ranging from the Folder Options GPO (open with) to importing registry keys via GPO (which works to some extent however normally it bugs out and each time the user is asked to choose a program to open the file with).

I've also set the default programs in the Default user profile before the image was rolled out. This did not work, asking some users to select a program to open the file with and others defaulted to metro apps.

Has anyone discovered a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this blog post here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mrmlcgn/archive/2013/02/26/windows-8-associate-a-file-type-or-protocol-with-a-specific-app-using-a-gpo-e-g-default-mail-client-for-mailto-protocol.aspx

Which resolved the issue. It uses a new group policy entry introduced in Server 2012 which specifies an XML file that holds the file type association mapping.

I have stored it on the domain's netlogon folder and so far it's all working correctly.